# Do we need to store google id_token in Back end?

Tags: authentication, jwt, backend, token

We implemented the google sign in feature recently. In back end we get id_token to authenticate user. For audit purpose, we need some record of this authentication. How do you do that? I currently inclined to saving the id_token and the time of request.